# Problems setting timestamp on for naming a file

Tags: batch-file, export, dump, oracle-export-dump

I want to set the name of a file that will be generated automatically by adding a timestamp to its name.

the batch file is as follows:

```
echo export database for HR account
SET YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%
exp hr/esprit parfile=D:\exp_imp_4DS1\parfile_exp.par
rem pause end of export
```

parfile_exp.par:

```
FILE=D:\exp_imp_4DS1\hr_%YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS%.dmp
GRANTS=Y
INDEXES=Y
ROWS=Y
COMPRESS=Y
```

Executing the bat file gives me this error:

```
EXP-00028: failed to open D:\exp_imp_4DS1\hr_/28/Fr 1_1136.dmp for write
```

Comment: The format of the strings produced for `%date%` and `%time%` depend on user-settings. W'e need to know what format you are using to suggest changes. You should be able to locate solutions using `[batch] date format` in the `search` box on the top bar.

Comment: Start by opening a Command Prompt window, type `ECHO {%DATE%}`. I'll bet that the output is not in the format `{MM/DD/YYYY}`. So you'll need to adjust the code for what that particular user, on that specific PC, and using their configured settings is using. Alternatively use the search facility at the top of the page to find the large number of questions and answers which can return the date in a known order/format on any PC.

Comment: Have a look at [StampMe.cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-stampme.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with WMIC to get date independent of user settings date

---

```bat
@echo off
Call:ReportName
echo %Report%
pause & exit
::*********************************************************************************
:ReportName
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set "stamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
Set "Report=%~dp0hr_%stamp%.dmp"
Exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Some versions of Windows 11 do not have WMIC. That's why I suggest the Robocopy method of getting the time and date in a locale independent format as described [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-stampme.html).